# How To Pass a query to a Database Server through sockets in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sockets

I'm currently working on a project in which:

1. the client connects to a database server (mysql for example) through sockets
2. once connected, the user queries the database and receives data back from the server using sockets

Sockets will serve as a driver to pass data from the server to the client.
I tried looking online but could not find any hint/solution

I would appreciate some help and guidance

Comment: Does the project required to use socket to access the database? If yes I think it will be very difficult. You should use `JDBC` and `mysql` driver instead. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/8.0.html

Comment: Yes, it requires to use sockets for every communication between the user and the database  server

Comment: What you are looking for it to re write JDBC driver from scratch. JDBC driver does the same things.

Comment: It's a  project (create a server that query a mysql database)